# awk -- replace once after immediate pattern in same line!

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

We have a 1.5MB file.
One particular line has about 160000 characters.
In the line we need to change "false" into "true" only once immediate after PATTERN.

Following awk only changes first occurrence.
But we need the change only after "PATTERN" once.

```bsh
awk '/PATTERN.*false/ {sub("false", "true")} {print}' file
```

Our file contains:

```
...
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is false colorC is false colorD is false
...
```

File need to have:

```
...
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false
...
```

How we can arrange awk command to fit our need?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Will `PATTERN` always be without a whitespace? After `PATTERN`, will there always be " is true" (exactly), when you have to change it to " is false"?

Comment: `PATTERN` Will have no whitespace. Between `PATTERN` and `true` have unknown  number of words.

Comment: That last part is going to be a problem, because `awk` regular expressions are greedy. That means a RegExp `PATTERN.*false` will match everything up to the very last `false` on the line. You may have to resort to a `perl`-based solution where greedyness can be turned off.

Comment: Is there any way you can specify how the next such expression on the line starts. In your example, it was always `colorX`. Can we rely on a fixed pattern for the next word after the `false` you want to turn into `true`?

Comment: Words of the line are unknown. We only know, there is one "PATTERN" and more than 50 "false" in different places in that line. Everything else is unknown.

Comment: @Amelia Please [edit] your question and all all requested information there instead of answering in comments. My suggestion is to split the line at `PATTERN`, substitute the first `false` in the second part and combine the parts. Are you sure that the first `false` after `PATTERN` belongs to `PATTERN`? Or in other words: Are you sure that the value that belongs to `PATTERN` is always `false` and not `true`? What about a line `colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst in theory it is possible to write a regular expression which matches the shortest string which doesn't match "false", it is hard. Various other languages have a syntax to choose shortest, but awk is not one of them.

So there are 3 approaches that can be used, assuming that you don't want to write the hard expression.

1. You can split the input on the word "false", loop over the fields, if the current field matches the pattern then print it out followed by "true", otherwise print it out followed by "false".
2. You can use a trick, convert all occurrences of "false" into a single unused character like control-a, then the regular expression is easy to write as you can say [^\001]*\001 to match the shortest pattern ending in control-a.
3. You just loop over the fields, if the current field is your pattern you set a flag, if it is "false" and the flag is set you change it to "true" and reset the flag.

For approach number 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

/PATTERN.*false/ {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                if ($i ~ /PATTERN/) flag=1;
                if ($i == "false" && flag==1) {
                        $i="true"
                        flag=0
                }
        }
}
{print}
```

This will collapse the whitespace in the input.

Comment: Thanks icarus! We appreciate your attention.

Comment: @AdminBee I am sure my program answers the question as currently written, which is to change the first "false" after PATTERN to "true".  The OP said there will be an unknown number of words after PATTERN, and there is no restriction on none of these words being "true". If this is a problem then adding `if ($i == "true") flag=0;` will fix it.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Error on my side!

Answer (score 0):

This solution implements the approach to split the line at `PATTERN` (`split`), substitute the first `false` in the second part (`sub`) and combine the parts (`for` loop and `printf`). The `next` command skips further processing of this input line. Other lines are printed unchanged. (`1` is an always true condition with default action.)

```
awk '/PATTERN.*false/ {
    n=split($0,parts,"PATTERN"); 
    sub("false", "true", parts[2]); 
    for(i=1;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%s%s", parts[i], "PATTERN");
    }
    printf("%s\n", parts[n]);
    next }
1'
```

It is unclear from the question if the value that corresponds to `PATTERN` is always `false`, so it may replace a wrong `false`.

Sample input

```
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is false colorC is false colorD is false
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false
```

results in this output

```
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is true colorD is false
```

**Edit** according to [RudiC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/303610/rudic)'s comment: If the to-be-modified value after PATTERN is either "true" or "false", then this possible problem can be avoided by replacing the instruction `sub("false", "true", parts[2]);` with `sub("false|true", "true", parts[2]);`

```
awk '/PATTERN.*false/ {
    n=split($0,parts,"PATTERN"); 
    sub("false|true", "true", parts[2]); 
    for(i=1;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%s%s", parts[i], "PATTERN");
    }
    printf("%s\n", parts[n]);
    next }
1'
```

With the same sample input this results in

```
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false
```

Comment: If the to-be-modified value after PATTERN is either "true" or "false", then `sub (/true|false/, "true", parts[2]` will get the deal done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*PATTERN)(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] gensub(/false/,"true",1,a[2])} 1' file
...
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false
...
```

and with any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/.*PATTERN/){tail=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH); sub(/false/,"true",tail); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1) tail } 1' file
...
colorA is false colorB is false PATTERN is true colorC is false colorD is false
...
```